# VBA Public Variable Not Working - MS Word - Counting Characters in a Table

Tags: vba, variables, ms-word

The main VBA procedure counts characters in table cells in a Word document.  Since it can count characters different ways:

- Count the "Objective" text for the selected table
- Count the "Accomplishment" text for the selected table
- Count both the Obj and Acc texts in each table (loop), for all tables (another loop)

I created calling procedures for each option above that calls the main procedure.  This way I pass variables from the calling Sub to the main Sub. These variables (1) tell the main Sub whether I want to count what is in row 3 (objective) or in row 5 (accomplishment) or both, and (2) feed the If/then lines in the main Sub to make sure the right row is counted.  *At the time, it seemed elegant, in hindsight - not so much.*

Word template below:
[image: word template]

There will be text in O1 and the VBA will count it (characters, spaces + paragraphs) and output it in C1, and the C1 fill changes red or green if over/under the character limit.  The same for A1 and C2 and so on for any number of following tables.

***PROBLEM DESCRIPTION***
The VBA was working for the actions above when I had the row/columns hard coded into various places in the code.  If rows/columns were ever added/deleted from the tables, they would have to updated in multiple spots.  It would be simpler if the row/column numbers were in one place and referred back to as variables, so I changed the row/col #s to public variables.  Then the problem began.

In the code, I track (debug.print) what becomes of `oRow` (output row) & `chcct` (character count col) and both are 0 as the main Sub runs, despite both being initialized as 3 in the public Sub Row_Col_Num() below.

My public variables are at the top of the module before the first Sub() and denoted as `Public`.  Sub Row_Col_Num() which contains the variable assignments is also `Public`.  All Subs are in the same standard module.

```
Option Explicit

 Public oRow As Integer      'row with "Objectives" text
 Public aRow As Integer      'row with "Accomplishments" text
 Public cOnA As Integer      'column that both obj and accmp text are in
 Public cChCt As Integer     'column that the char count is output to

Public Sub Row_Col_Num()
    oRow = 3
    aRow = 5
    cOnA = 1
    cChCt = 3
Debug.Print "cchct pub sub: " & cChCt
End Sub
```

***ATTEMPTS TO FIX PROBLEM & RESULTS***

1. I used the variable normally and left it `Public` as well as the Sub that assigns the variables (`oRow =3`) values.

```
Sub TableCharCount_Obj()
'Run character count for the "Objectives"  in the SELECTED table
Debug.Print "orow = " & oRow
Call TableCharCount(oRow, oRow)   'provide it 2x to make IF and FOR loop
End Sub
```

2. I tried putting the Sub() name in front of the variable when it is used, e.g. Row_Col_Num.orow, in the Sub above.
   `Call TableCharCount(Row_Col_Num.oRow, Row_Col_Num.oRow)`
3. I tried the module name in front of the variable as well, e.g. Module1.orow.
   `Call TableCharCount(Module1.oRow, Module1.oRow)`

***RESULTS***
#1 & #3 resulted in the macro counting the wrong row and outputting to the wrong cell.
#2 resulted in error "Expected Function or variable" at line:  `Call TableCharCount(Row_Col_Num.oRow, Row_Col_Num.oRow)`
All 3 cases `orow` and `cchct` both continued to be 0 throughout the run.

***QUESTIONS / SOLUTIONS***
a)  Can a Public variable (`oRow`) be used as an argument passed from calling Sub to called Sub as `ByVal a As Integer`?

b) Does Public Sub Row_Col_Num(), which assigns values to the public variables, have to be explicitly run or called to populate the variables in the other Subs w/ the correct values?

c) Should I call Public Sub Row_Col_Num() in every calling Sub before calling the main Sub?

```
Sub TableCharCount_Obj()
Call Public Sub Row_Col_Num()  '<<< add this call
Call TableCharCount(oRow, oRow)   'provide it 2x to make IF and FOR loop
End Sub
```

This option seems like a bad design.

If it's not obvious, there was some mission creep as I added more capability   For now, if I could get the public variables to work, it would be done. Appreciate any suggestion to get these variables to work. For the purposes of this question, I only left the code for the variable Sub, the first calling Sub and the main Sub.  VBA below:

```
'#0 -- This creates variables for column and row number used in all the macros.  Only need to change row/col number here if row/col are added/deleted  

Option Explicit

Public oRow As Integer      'row with "Objectives" text   
Public aRow As Integer      'row with "Accomplishments" text   
Public cOnA As Integer      'column that both obj and accmp text are in   
Public cChCt As Integer     'column that the char count is output to

'This assigns row/column numbers to the variables
Public Sub Row_Col_Num()
    oRow = 3
    aRow = 5
    cOnA = 1
    cChCt = 3  
Debug.Print "cchct pub sub: " & cChCt End Sub

'#2  
Sub TableCharCount_Obj() 'Run character count for the "Objectives" in the SELECTED table  
Debug.Print "orow = " & oRow  
Call TableCharCount(oRow, oRow)   'provide it 2x to make IF and FOR loop  
End Sub  

'other calling procedures removed

'#5  
Option Explicit  
Sub TableCharCount(ByVal a As Integer, ByVal b As Integer)  
'Counts total characters in a cell w/in a table and outputs the number to a different cell, and colors the cell red or green if over/under the maximum number of characters.

Dim charCount, charWSCount, paraCount, charTot As Double  
Dim iRng, oRng, txtRng As Word.Range  
Dim i, max, s, t, x As Integer  
Dim tcount, tbl As Integer  
Dim DocT As Table           'for active doc tables

Debug.Print "cchct1= " & cChCt 'Debug.Print vbCr & "-----START-------" & vbCr Application.ScreenUpdating = False

If a <> b Then
    tcount = ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
    tbl = 1                 'used in FOR loop, start w/ table #1
    s = b - a     '"STEP" used in FOR loop = # of rows between objectives text and accomplishments text Else
    On Error GoTo ErrMsg    'handles expected user error of not selecting a table to execute on
    tbl = ActiveDocument.Range(0, Selection.Tables(1).Range.End).Tables.Count       'ID the table that is selected
    tcount = tbl            'prevents FOR loop from trying to run again
    s = 1    '"STEP" used in FOR loop = # of rows between objectives text and accomplishments text / do not set to zero = infinite loop End If

'Debug.Print "# of Tables: " & tcount

For t = tbl To tcount                       'loops thru the tables
    Set DocT = ActiveDocument.Tables(t)
    For x = a To b Step s                   'loops thru the applicable row(s) in the table
            'Debug.Print "x @ start = " & x
            'Debug.Print "table " & t
            iRng = DocT.Cell(x, cOnA)
            iRng.Select
      
        'Count used in output
            Selection.MoveLeft wdCharacter, 1, wdExtend     'computerstats requires the text itself selected, characters.count can use the whole cell selected
            charWSCount = Selection.Range.ComputeStatistics(Statistic:=wdStatisticCharactersWithSpaces) 'counts bullets & space after bullet / not line breaks (paragraphs)
            'Debug.Print "Comp statchar#  " & charWSCount
        '---------
            paraCount = Selection.Range.ComputeStatistics(Statistic:=wdStatisticParagraphs)
            'Debug.Print "#paras = " & paraCount             
        '----------
            charTot = charWSCount + paraCount
                
        'Output to table cell
            i = x - 1                           'output cell is 1 row above cell that is counted
            Set oRng = DocT.Cell(i, cChCt).Range    'Char count ouput row,column
    Debug.Print "cchct2= " & cChCt
            
            oRng.Text = charTot
            Set txtRng = DocT.Cell(i, cChCt - 1).Range    '"# Char:" location row,column
            txtRng.Text = "# Char:"
            
        
        'Maximum # of char allowed in a cell.  Used to change cell fill red or green.
            max = 2000                              '"Accomplishment" row (row 5) has a max of 2000
            If i = 2 Then max = 1500                '"Objective" row (row 3) has a max of 1500
        
        'Change color of cell to indicate over/under max # of characters
            If charCount < max Then
                oRng.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorBrightGreen
                Else: oRng.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = wdColorRed
            End If
            
            'Debug.Print "x @ end = " & x
            'Debug.Print "--------Next x--------------"
        
    Next x
    
    'Debug.Print "------Next Table------"

Next t

ActiveDocument.Tables(tbl).Select       'attempt to move to top of 1st table if using CharCount_AllTab() or just to the top of the selected table for the other macros  
Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page" Selection.StartOf

Application.ScreenUpdating = True  
Exit Sub

ErrMsg: Msgbox "Select a table by placing the cursor anywhere in the table.  Press OK and try the macro again numnuts!", _
    vbOKOnly, "Table not selected"  
End Sub
```

Comment: The `Option Explicit` in the middle of the code is illegal, module options are only legal at module level. Is that code block actually two modules?

Comment: Also `Selection.GoTo What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\Page",Selection.StartOf` is illegal because you can't mix named and non-named arguments like that. If your code doesn't compile, how are you running into any run-time errors? See [mcve]...